# Magento Shell Issue

Tags: mysql, pdo, magento-1.5

I am working on Magento store running fine on UBUNTU server. Yesterday I have changed Database password & make same changes in local.xml file & after clean cache website working fine but shell is not working

Giving below error.

```
-115:~/public_html/shell$ php -f abc.php
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)' in /home/test/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:129
Stack trace:
#0 /home/test/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(129): PDO->__construct('mysql:model=mys...', 'root', 'MYOLDPASSWORD', Array)
#1 /home/test/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#2 /home/test/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(251): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /home/test/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(459): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#4 /home/test/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /home/test/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(337): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#6 /home/test/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Type/Db/Pdo/Mysql. in /home/test/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 144
```

What I need to update more. 
Please help

Comment: Is this your root password there? :O

Comment: this is my old password & i have changed it with new one